# Подскажите в чем дело скрипт останавливается на "var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();"

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet

```
function onEditPrice(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var idCol = e.range.getColumn();
  var idRow = e.range.getRow();
  
  if( sheet.getName() == 'Продажи' ){
    var tcol = 3;
    var toffset = 1;
    var trange = 1;
    var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Поступление товара");
    var sourceData = sourceSheet.getRange(1, 1, sourceSheet.getLastRow(),10).getDisplayValues();
    var idProd = sheet.getRange(idRow, 2).getValue();
  }
  
  if( idCol == tcol ){
    if(sheet.getRange(idRow, idCol).getValue()=== ''){
      sheet.getRange(idRow, idCol + trange).setValue("пустость");
    }
    else{
      for(var row = 0; row<sourceData.length; row++){
        if(sourceData[row][1] == idProd && sourceData[row][5]>0){
            let buyCost = +((sourceData[row][6]).replace(/\s+/g, '').replace(',','.').slice(0,-2));
            let sellCost = +((sourceData[row][7]).replace(/\s+/g, '').replace(',','.').slice(0,-2));
            let prodCount =  +sourceData[row][3];
          
             sheet.getRange(idRow, idCol + trange + 2).setValue(prodCount);
             sheet.getRange(idRow, idCol + trange).setValue(buyCost);
             sheet.getRange(idRow, idCol + trange + 1).setValue(sellCost);
          break;
          }
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Ошибка
TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined
onEditPrice @ priceCalc.gs:2

Данный скрипт был сделан в 20году, и недавно я обратил внимание, что он перестал работать.
UDP исправил переменную (e) не помогло
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте лог ошибки, скрипт не может просто остановиться. Допускаю, что вы не приняли event в функции onEdit и пытаетесь обращаться к ключам значения undefined

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: `e` откуда берется? `function onEdit(e) {...}`, наверно, должно быть

Comment: Ошибка говорит о том, что у вас ивент пустой.

Comment: @mryogurt, я прошу прощения, как он может быть пуст?

Comment: Это у вас надо спрашивать, судя по тому, что изначально его вы даже не приняли в функции, предполагаю, могли и не передать

Comment: Также может ивент и не пустой, но там нет ключа source

Comment: Изначально я прислал код в котором пытался исправить эту ошибку, и не вернул его в исходное состояние перед отправкой сюда.

Comment: @MrYogurt а как добавить это  ключ? я просто не понимаю, в гугле не удается найти что либо, заранее спасибо

Comment: Как по вашему я должен понять что либо в этом куске кода? Проводите дебаг и смотрите пришел ли вообще ивент, если пришел, то откуда и что в теории должно передаваться

Comment: Дело в том, что это весь код и он запинается в первых 3х строках, он используется в гугл таблицах

Comment: Это не весь код, ибо что то как минимум должно запускать функцию

Comment: Добавил скриншот

Comment: Скриншот ни о чем не говорит, кроме того, что у вас ивент undefined. Скрипты в гугл таблицах я не писал, но предполагаю, что пропала связь скрипта с тем, что он обрабатывает.